# TestNG Results Trend in Jenkins does not show failed tests or builds

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testing, automation, testng

As you can see, I have failed build which are not showing in the graph.I have searched the Internet but apparently I am the only one having this issue.
[Image of Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpVBI.png)

These are my dependencies in pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Failed build doesnt have to mean there are any failed tests, please check your build console output

Comment: My test is Assert.assertTrue(false) to deliberately to fail the test and it does not show the whole build in the table. even though there are other tests